# Generating PDF - what do I need?

Tags: symfony, pdf

I'm trying to generate PDF in my symfony 2 application - what do I need to do that? Right now I downloaded through composer the following bundle:

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

But trying to generate pdf using it gives me an error:

```
The exit status code '126' says something went wrong:
stderr: "sh: /var/www/html/khernik/app/../web/files: is a directory
"
stdout: ""
```

---

I think the problem lies in the configuration - `app/config/config.yml`:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     %kernel.root_dir%/../web/files
        options:    []
```

The binary line...where should it point to? I've read it should be some executable file...does knp bundle provide it? I've also tried downloading the following bundle:

https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64

But it gives me the following composer error:

```
no matching package found
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) first and you will get a binary file then. After installation, you can run it to verify that installation is correct

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

after that set binary in KnpSnappyBundle settings. To get wkhtmltopdf binary path type in terminal

```
which wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: I have to install it on amazon linux...Is there a way to do that rather with some external library?

Comment: whats the problem to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Install wkhtmltopdf and then configure config.yml. Download wkhtmltopdf:

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

After that configure config.yml. Binary is path to the wkhtmltopdf.

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
        options:    []
```